# Replicate axis region reference frame and drawing to it (saving coordinates, 2D and 3D)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to have a command that fills the `axis` region with a diamond pattern. The diamond pattern may have different offset, scale and drawing styles, but it's important it is exact w.r.t. the axis (it's a "plot"). That should go in the background behind the other plots, and should work with 2D and 3D graphics.

My first solution was to save the coordinates within the `axis` environment, and then draw outside the `axis`, within a `pgfonlayer`. It does not feel especially clean, but it works, in 2D. In 3D, not so much. Here is what I have, I tried to make it as compact as possible:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,patterns}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}


\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % \begin{scope}[
    %   x={(-0.7cm,0.4cm)},
    %   y={(.9cm,.2cm)},
    %   z={(0cm,1cm)},
    %   canvas is yx plane at z=0
    % ]

      \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal, xmin=-.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=-.5, ymax=4.5]

          % Save the coordinates of the axis frame and the unit of the plot
          \coordinate (rel axis llc) at (rel axis cs: 0, 0);
          \coordinate (rel axis urc) at (rel axis cs: 1, 1);
          \coordinate (axis unit llc) at (axis cs: 0, 0);
          \coordinate (axis unit urc) at (axis cs: 1, 1);

          % Some genuine plotting
          \addplot[black, opacity=0.5] {(x-3)^2};

          % Debug:
          \fill[red] (rel axis llc) circle (3pt);
          \fill[red] (rel axis urc) circle (3pt);
          \fill[green] (axis unit llc) circle (3pt);
          \fill[green] (axis unit urc) circle (3pt);

        \end{axis}
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Debug:
        \fill[blue] (rel axis llc) circle (3pt);
        \fill[blue] (rel axis urc) circle (3pt);

        % Here we set the clip at the axis area
        \clip (rel axis llc) rectangle (rel axis urc);

        % Do maths to extract the same unit as it was used in the axis.
        % This is probably extra cumbersome
        \extractcoord{\dx}{\dy}{$(axis unit urc)-(axis unit llc)$}
        \extractcoord{\minx}{\miny}{$(rel axis llc)-(axis unit llc)$}
        \extractcoord{\maxx}{\maxy}{$(rel axis urc)-(axis unit llc)$}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\minx}{div(\minx, \dx) - 1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\miny}{div(\miny, \dy) - 1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxx}{div(\maxx, \dx) + 1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxy}{div(\maxy, \dy) + 1)}
        \makeatletter
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ux}{\dx * \pgf@xx}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\uy}{\dy * \pgf@yy}
        \makeatother
        % Shift at the same position and set the correct unit
        \begin{scope}[shift={(axis unit llc)}, x=\ux, y=\uy, xstep=1, ystep=1]
          % Here goes the diamond writing code, will just use a rectangle
          \draw [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.3]
            (\minx, \miny) rectangle (\maxx, \maxy);
          \draw [pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, opacity=0.3]
            (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
        \end{scope}
      \end{pgfonlayer}

    % \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I get (which is ok):

[image: Correctly saving coordinates]

The goal would be this (that is why I need both the axis frame and the unit square), but I did not want to bloat the MVE with the diamond code:

[image: What I would like to have in the end]

In fact, I made an environment out of this, because I need to replicate it several times. Now, if I try to do it in 3D, the scale outside the `axis` environment is off. This is what happens if I enable the `scope` that are commented out in the example above:

[image: The same technique does not work in 3D]

I really do not understand what is happening that causes the coordinates that I save to "change apparent position" when using 3D graphics, and I think I'm lacking the knowledge about PGF and TikZ to be able to figure out a more solid way to do this.

Any explanation or suggestion on how to redesign the entire thing is appreciated.

Comment: Is this [an answer](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1831) for your question?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 it is, most definitely. I also appreciate the warnings about the danger. If the author would like to post it, I'd be happy to reward it.

Comment: He is not here.

Comment: In that case, I would reward also an answer linking to the original material and explaining the rationale behind it.

Comment: About reward, I think, it is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this has been [answered here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1831#a2061). The solution, essentially, is not to save the axis environment geometry for future usage, but rather to draw directly into the axis environment using `execute at begin axis`:

```
\pgfplotsset{draw xy background/.style={%
  execute at begin axis={
    % Get the axis area and populate macros \myxmin, \myxmax, \myymin, \myymax
    \pgfplotsset{get xy window}%
    % Drawing code that uses the macros above.
    % Here you can use the (axis cs: X, Y) reference frame
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
\begin{axis}[xmin=-.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=-.5, ymax=4.5, draw xy background]
  % ...                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\end{axis}
```

The `get xy window` key is quite interesting because it gets the axis area using some internals of pgfplots:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
  get xy window/.code={%
    % Enable floating point processing
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
    % Convert each internal macro of pgfplots into fixed point
    % representation and store the result of that operation into
    % the corresponding \myXXXX macro
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplots@xmax}\let\myxmax\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplots@xmin}\let\myxmin\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplots@ymax}\let\myymax\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplots@ymin}\let\myymin\pgfmathresult
    % Disable floating point
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  }
}
\makeatother
```

I am not sure why it needs the floating point engine on, but I'm guessing that `\pgfplots@xmax` and the other macros are actually in floating point, so we need to convert them to fixed explicitly.

Note that, since the drawing code now runs **within** the axis environment, we could use `rel axis cs:` to reference the axis bounds. However, since in this specific case I need to draw for each x and y separately, using `\pgfplots@minx` and friends is much more handy than the `\extractcoord` macro defined above.

Also, if `get xy window` is not used anywhere else, we can compress everything into a single key by pulling the code of `get xy window` into `execute at begin axis`.

---